# How to convert html special characters to different format in python?

Tags: python

I am retrieving a querystring from an API but I need it in another format for a different API.  How can I use python3 to convert querystring1 so it'll be in the format given in querystring2?
What character format is querystring1 and querystring2 in? They both should decode to 'q=score:>=100'.

```
querystring1 = 'q=score%3A%26amp%3Bgt%3B%3D100'

querystring2 = 'q=score%3A%3E%3D100'
```

Comment: Where do these strings come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second of these is a simple encoded querystring, which can be parsed with `urllib.parse.unquote`:

```
from urllib import parse
parse.unquote('q=score%3A%3E%3D100')
```

The first is trickier, because it's a querystring that (wrongly) contains double-encoded HTML entities. You need to use `html.unescape` to translate them:

```
import html
html.unescape(parse.unquote('q=score%3A%26amp%3Bgt%3B%3D100'))
```

To convert version 1 to version 2, you can parse and then re-encode. Note, you need to pass it through `html.escape` *twice*; the first will translate `>` to `&gt;`, the second will translate that to `&amp;gt;`. (To be honest, you should really look into fixing whatever API is expecting that format, it's totally broken.)

```
data = parse.unquote('q=score%3A%3E%3D100')
parse.quote(html.escape(data))
```